# Why does submit button demand a local resource request to favicon.ico?

Tags: html

I've got a very basic form here in which I want to test whether the input text value is correctly picked up when clicking the submit button.

```html
<form id="form1" onSubmit="console.log(document.getElementById('inkomen1').value)">
      <input type="text" id="inkomen1" name="inkomen1">
      <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So I've set the form onSubmit to display the contents of the input text field through console.log. Live this works, but locally I always get this strange error in my console:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///favicon.ico

Why doesn't this work when I text the file locally and why this request for 'favicon.ico'? Can I make it work locally somehow too?

Comment: do you have any meta tags pointing at the favicon?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the form. Just has to do with the fact the browser is looking for a icon file. (and testing on file protocol is not the best thing)

Answer (score 0):

It's has nothing to do with the code you included in your question. You have an HTML code that has a link to a favicon. The link has an absolute path `file:///favicon.ico` which is not correct when running your code in a different environment.

Use a relative path, if your favicon is in the same path as your HTML you can set it to:

```
/favicon.ico
```

**UPDATE**

Try to add custom action to your form

```
<form id="form1" action"targetPageHere" onSubmit="console.log(document.getElementById('inkomen1').value)">
```

Maybe the default action page is not your page and has a different code that include this reference.

Comment: Above is the only code I'm using. There isn't any favicon.ico code anywhere, just the form code. When I use 'alert' the contents of that input field is shown as expected. But console.log only works when testing remote. When I test the html file locally I get this strange favicon.ico request

Comment: This error only comes from a browser who tries to get a resource and can't find it. You might have an HTML code that wraps your code. In your browser, right click and select "view source", you'll probably see the favicon link under the head tag

Comment: Copy just above 'form' code and paste it into a new index.html file. Open that index.html file and fill the text field with a value like '234'. Then click submit. You will see in the console that you'll get that favicon.ico error or some kind of local resource request. Which is totally illogical since it shouldn't be looking for favicon.ico or any other file. As only that <form> code is present. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I did test it. Add this code to an empty text file, change the suffix to .html and run it with your browser - you won't get any error

Comment: It's already html. Here's my file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ec1ddd2817572de2888777a1e2413fc920190129151612/b6a21c. When I test it by opening it in either Safari for Mac or Chrome it doesn't work. In Safari I get this 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///favicon.ico' message shown in the console after filling the input field with '234' and then hitting Submit. And Chrome doesn't display anything at all. It DOES work when uploading the test.html file and testing it remotely. But opening the test.html file locally it doesn't.

Comment: For sure the problem is not in this code - I ran it on chrome locally just for sanity, but obviously, this code doesn't include any reference to favicon so it can't produce such error. Check if you have a different code/HTML that run before or after.

Comment: No, again, it's only above <form> code. And it doesn't happen all the time. Mostly when entering 'new' numbers and hitting Submit. When I enter e.g. 234 I get this error in console on Safari and nothing in Chrome's console (remains blank), entering 234 again and hitting Submit, then nothing happens. When I enter 2345 I again get this error in Safari and no console content in Chrome. The next time I enter 2345 nothing again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187501/discussion-between-itay-gal-and-jiggy1965).